# Algorithm for placing rooks on a $nxn$ chessboard such that they attack exactly $m$ squares

Tags: algorithm

Suppose there is a chessboard with dimensions nxn and you put rooks on the chessboard such that they collectively attack m squares on that chessboard. Given n and m, how can you determine how many rooks must be placed on the chessboard, and where to put them?

For example, let's say that the board dimensions are 3x3 and you have to cover 9 squares on the board by placing rooks. To do this, or to simply cover the board with rooks such that there are no safe squares, you can put 3 rooks in the coordinates (1,1);(1,2);(1,3) on the board (the first number in the coordinate is the column number, the second is the row number). That way, since a rook attacks all squares in the same row and column as where it stands, all 9 squares are attacked.

But how can you find the optimal coordinates for any n and m with an algorithm?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: It's a problem that can be solved by writing a program, so how is it off topic? @melpomene

Comment: Many problems can be solved by writing a program, but what you're asking about is a very artificial problem (placing rooks on chessboards of arbitrary size) and the answer is a mathematical proof (you'd need to come up with an algorithm, then prove it correct). This is not a coding problem.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll post it to math stackexchange then, thank you for clarifying .@melpomene

Comment: I'd like to add that so far I'm the only one who thinks this question is off-topic here, but two other people voted to close it as "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

If you cover **x** rows and **y** columns, then you cover **N(x+y) - xy** squares, and it takes **max(x,y)** rooks.

A simple algorithm to solve your problem would try to calculate the matching value of **y** for each possible value of **x**, and remember the solution that requires the fewest rooks.

For a more sophisticated solution that works for bigger problems, notice that **-(N-x)(N-y) = N(x+y) - xy - N^2**

If there is a solution that covers **X** rows and **y** columns to attack **m** squares, then:

**m = -(N-x)(N-y) + N^2**

so

**(N-x)(N-y) = N^2 - m**

Each solution therefore corresponds to a factoring of **N^2 - m** into a product, and the solution that takes the fewest number of rooks is the one with the factors closest together.  You can start at **sqrt(N^2 - m)** and count down until you find a divisor, or use Fermat's factorization method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method

Comment: I understand the n(x+y) term, but why would the number need to be subtracted by xy?

Comment: @HehexDKappa123 Because of the inclusion-exclusion principle.  You add all of the ones covered by horizontal lines.  Then by vertical lines.  Then subtract the intersection.